# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n}=x$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n}=x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$? I see that $\lfloor nx\rfloor = n\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor n(x-\lfloor x \rfloor )\rfloor + O(1)$ but I'm not sure how to deal with the middle term.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**
Use the squeeze theorem with the inequalites
$$nx-1<\lfloor nx\rfloor\leq nx$$

Answer (score 5):

Why not start from $nx=\lfloor nx\rfloor +e_n(x)$, where $0\le e_n(x)\lt 1$?